# Is pygame.time.delay() better than time.sleep()?

Tags: python, time, pygame, delay, source-code-protection

Is it wrong to think that `pygame.time.delay(1000)` is more accurate than `time.sleep(1)`.

Does the pygame module *use* time.sleep() in its source code, or are they completely different?

Comment: Not to sound snarky but for "Does the pygame module use time.sleep() in its source code, or are they completely different?" you could probably look that up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PyGame is based on [Simple DirectMedia Layer (SDL)](https://wiki.libsdl.org/). [`pygame.time.delay()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.delay) is delegated to [`SDL_Delay`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Delay). The implementation of `SDL_Delay` depends on the operating system.